# Raster Widgets for Web AppBuilder

Tags: raster, arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget

I am trying to find a general raster widget to use in a custom Web AppBuilder app, but I am not seeing anything out of the box. I basically just need a widget to plug into the app that would display just raster layer. My goal is to then select a raster layer from the dialog window and be able to click or mouse over that layer and have info displayed as a popup about that raster layer. My question are 1) Are there any out of the box raster widgets that fit the bill and/or 2) Any suggestions for a custom widget that would work? I am checking [custom widgets from Web AppBuilder - The custom widgets list (4/5/2018)](https://community.esri.com/blogs/myAlaskaGIS/2017/03/04/web-appbuilder-the-custom-widgets-list-332017) , but not seeing anything popout.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your raster layers are published as Image Services, there are a variety of widgets for working with those at [github.com/Esri/WAB-Image-Services-Widgets](https://github.com/Esri/WAB-Image-Services-Widgets).